# Video and music editing applications?

Tags: 14.04, video-editor

Video and music editing software that can be used on Ubuntu 14.04? I installed Kdenlive, and seems to work okay, except that it tends to slow down the system a little. It also takes a bit of time to get your head around it. But I was wondering if there were other alternatives that I should try out as well.

Comment: I edited your question so that it won't be opinion based....

Comment: we tend to close new list based questions.  For the moment I've dupe'd this against an existing Q that gives you various recommendations in this area.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/) and [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) are good video and audio editors respectively.

Installation:

Directly from Software Centre:

- OpenShot  install from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openshot/)
- Audacity install from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/)

From Terminal:(Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
sudo apt-get install openshot
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Alternatively you can use Pitivi  video editor,

Installation:

From Software Centre [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/pitivi/) or from terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install pitivi
```

Answer (score 0):

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is the best video editor available in my opinion.

**Installation :**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

---

For music editing you should give a try to [Audacity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/) which is available in Ubuntu Software center.

**Installation :**

[image: Install via the software center]

Or in command line :

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

---

Those both applications are free and open-source.

Comment: you are too fast..;)  =)+1